# How to add lines and shades in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset and want to make a plot for it. My data and plot codes are:

```
#Data
Days<-c("-6","-6","-6","-1","-1","-1","1","6","6","6","13","13","13","16","20","20","20","24","28","28","28","44","44","44")
Event<-c("","","","","","","H","","","","","","","P","","","","H","","","","","","")
Dummy<-c("","","","","","","1","","","","","","","1","","","","1","","","","","","")
Item <-c("DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP")
Result <- c("100","68","149","98","80","142","","98","88","142","110","72","160","","102","69","159","","99","82","136","97","84","144")
#Dataframe
Sample.data <- data.frame( Days, Event,Dummy, Item, Result,stringsAsFactors = F) 
Sample.data %>% mutate(ID=1) %>% mutate (Name="Jack")

#Plot
ggplot(type.convert(Sample.data)) + 
  geom_line(aes(Days, Result, group = Item, color = Item))+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept=120)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=80)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Days, y =Dummy ))+
  geom_text(aes(x = Days, y =Dummy,label=Event,Vjust = 1.75))
```

the plot I got is:
[image]
I wants to further improve it but don't know how. Could anyone help one on this:

1. I want to add vertical dash line on where the event is marked;
2. I want to shade the area between the line (y=120 and Y=80);
3. I don't want to plot the line when Item=="" (THERE IS no line for it, but it did show in legend ;
4. I wants to add Name to the footnote or title. Please note I want sth like Sample.data$Name instead of "Jack", as I am doing plots for more than 1 person and I will use loop codes to generate plots, so Name need to auto change by itself.

It will looks like this:

[image]

sorry for the ugly plot. this is the best I can get by drawing. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
Days<-c("-6","-6","-6","-1","-1","-1","1","6","6","6","13","13","13","16","20","20","20","24","28","28","28","44","44","44")
Event<-c("","","","","","","H","","","","","","","P","","","","H","","","","","","")
Dummy<-c("","","","","","","1","","","","","","","1","","","","1","","","","","","")
Item <-c("DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP","DIABP","PULSE","SYSBP")
Result <- c("100","68","149","98","80","142","","98","88","142","110","72","160","","102","69","159","","99","82","136","97","84","144")
#Dataframe
Sample.data <- data.frame( Days, Event,Dummy, Item, Result,stringsAsFactors = F) 
Sample.data %>% mutate(ID=1) %>% mutate (Name="Jack")
#Create flags
Sample.data$Flag <- ifelse(Sample.data$Dummy==1,Sample.data$Days,NA)
#Plot
ggplot(type.convert(Sample.data)) + 
  geom_line(aes(Days, Result, group = Item, color = Item))+ 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Days,ymin=80,ymax=120),fill='blue',alpha=0.2)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=120)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=80)+
  geom_point(aes(x = Days, y =Dummy ))+
  geom_text(aes(x = Days, y =Dummy,label=Event,Vjust = 1.75))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=Flag),lty='dashed')+
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=unique(Sample.data$Item[Sample.data$Item!='']))+
  labs(title='Jack',caption = 'Jack')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You are fast! What I should do if I want DIABP and SYSBP to the the line, and Pulse to be the dots?

Comment: When I use ` geom_ribbon(aes(x=Days,ymin=80,ymax=120),fill='blue',alpha=0.2)' in my real data, I got the error message `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Stataq Your Days variable must be like factor or other type. In order to change the line type try `scale_linetype_manual()`

Comment: Just check Days type: [1] "numeric". What should I do? For Pulse, I want to use points, and DIABP and SYSBP  still line plot.  can I add a fliter in some where to  limit `Item %in% c("DIABP", "SYSBP")` ?

Comment: @Stataq Check in the breaks options for what you want around `scale_color_discrete()` you can add another different item like `breaks=unique(Sample.data$Item[Sample.data$Item %in% c("DIABP", "SYSBP")]`

Comment: When I use ` geom_ribbon(aes(x=Days,ymin=80,ymax=120),fill='blue',alpha=0.2)' in my real data, I got the error message Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale. The `Days` is  `[1] "numeric"`. Do I need to change something in order to add ribbon?

Comment: @Stataq It is weird the error you get, try running piece by piece the plot code!

Comment: Is it a way too add footnote or legend to explain what the ribbon and vertical line stands for in the plot? If so, how should i do it.

Comment: @Stataq You can do that with `labs()` you can add the text you want with options like title, subtitle or caption as I added in the post!

Comment: Is it a way to put legend for the blue ribbon, so people can know what it stands for. also for the hline we added by (y=100), is it a way to make a legend for it ? current legend only cover the three line we made using Item.

Comment: I tried `geom_ribbon(aes(x=Days,ymin=80,ymax=120),fill='blue',alpha=0.2, show.legend = T)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=120, show.legend = T)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=80, show.legend = T)+..` but it did not make a legend for it. it change the shade of legend for item in blue. Did I do wrong?

Comment: You could use some option like `fill` in general `aes()` to create a square with the color of your fill. Ribbons legend is not working for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221957/discussion-between-stataq-and-duck).

Comment: What do you mean fill in general aes() ? Even the line (y=80) (y=100) did not show legend?
Do we need legend for them? or we can get away by adding footnote. but I do have a very long footnote already

Comment: You have to create a fake legend for that what you want using fill!